# Select spans accross multiple divs issue

Tags: javascript, selection, range, html

I'm having the following issue - I'm trying to select the text inside spans located across multiple divs. To give an example

```
<div>asd<span>fgh</span></div>
<div><span>qwerty</span></div>
<div><span>uio</span>asd</div>
```

Now in this scenario, if the user clicks somewhere inside the word `qwerty` I'd like to select the text 'fghqwertuio' --> all the adjacent spans. I'm using the following code to do this:

```
    var range = document.caretRangeFromPoint(lastTappedX, lastTappedY);
    range.selectNodeContents(range.startContainer);
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);

    var containerNodes = document.body.children[0].children;
    var whichChild = -1;

    for ( var i = 0; i < containerNodes.length; ++i) {
        if (containerNodes[i] === range.startContainer.parentNode.parentNode) {
            whichChild = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (whichChild === -1) {
        console.log("couldn't find the highlighted div");
    }

    // go right the dom tree
    for ( var i = whichChild + 1; i < containerNodes.length; ++i) {
        var containerChildren = containerNodes[i].children;
        if (containerChildren[0]
                && containerChildren[0].style['background-color']) {
            var newRange = document.createRange();
            newRange.selectNodeContents(containerChildren[0]);
            window.getSelection().addRange(newRange);
        }

        if (containerChildren.length > 1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // go left the down tree
    for ( var i = whichChild - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        var containerChildren = containerNodes[i].children;
        if (containerChildren[containerChildren.length - 1].style['background-color']) {
            var newRange = document.createRange();
            newRange
                    .selectNodeContents(containerChildren[containerChildren.length - 1]);
            window.getSelection().addRange(newRange);
        }

        if (containerChildren.length > 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

When I log what happens - I'm correctly creating ranges containing the text I'd like to select but adding them to the selection object doesn't seem to work. The current selection is only the first added range. Any help on how to solve this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Simon: jQuery has nothing to deal with ranges and selections and will not help with the fundamental issue here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get your question. I created a short fiddle, maybe you can explain your question basing on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6rvE7/1/

Comment: @TimDown 10x for the answer. I was just reviewing it when refresh the page and saw that it is deleted. Can you repost?

Comment: I posted some code but realised I had made wrong assumptions about the spans being next to each other so deleted it. I've posted a cut down answer without code. For what it's worth, here's a jsFiddle with what I was going to post: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/P62kZ/2/

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I suffer from this problem too. I have code that highlights search results and was disappointed that it works only on firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the major browsers, only Firefox allows multiple ranges per selection. In all other browsers you're limited to one range.

You need to tweak your code to create one range and use the range's `setStart()` and `setEnd()` methods. Also, properties of the `style` property of elements use camel case rather than hyphens (i.e. `.backgroundColor` rather than `['background-color']`).

Comment: Is there any way to do this in chrome or IE? I wonder why the method was called addRange while it's possible to select only one range?

Comment: @AshrafSabry: No, there is no way to do it in anything other than Mozilla browsers. Mozilla made up the selection API and everyone else copied it, except for multiple range support, hence `addRange()` and `removeAllRanges()`.

Comment: Hey! You are the author of Rangy! It's a good coincidence. I tried using your library before I became sure that there's no support for multiple ranges in these browsers. When I see the "find and replace" functionality in chrome and the way it highlights search matches, I wonder why they didn't expose this highlighting functionality while they've already implemented it. Thanks for the good work.

Comment: @AshrafSabry: I wouldn't be surprised if Chrome does expose the highlighting functionality in some undocumented way.